# fetching a table with unique or distinct values?

Tags: mysql, t-sql, unique, distinct

i have this table:

```
post{id, user_id, event_id}
```

i want to fetch all posts thats have an event_id(not NULL) for a particular user, and i dnt want an event_id to occur again, i want it to be distinct, i.e if 2 posts have an event_id of 2, then i only need one of them to be retrieved, thanks!!!

i.e.

```
select count(*)
from posts
where user_id = '43'
and
//not null event id
//distinct event id's
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get the count of event id's:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT event_id)
FROM   posts 
WHERE  user_id = '43' 
  AND event_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Actually, `AND event_id IS NOT NULL` is unnecessary, I think. NULLs do not count, do they?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select distinct event_id 
from posts
where user_id='43' and event_id is not null
```

It is a bit more complex if you need id's instead, but can use this

```
select max(id)
from posts
where user_id='43' and event_id is not null
group by event_id
```

YOu can replace max(id) with min(id) if you want the first event number

Comment: thanks, but i want the count of the result!! is that possible

Answer (score 1):

```
select event_id, count(event_id)
from posts
where user_id=43 and event_id is not null
group by event_id;
```

`group by` is to get count for each unique of event_id